# destroy method gives weird error after upgrade to Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5

I had this thing working well in Laravel 4.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'delete','action'=>['ActionsController@destroy',$o->id]]) !!}

<button type="submit" class="fa fa-remove"></button>                      

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Now I get this error:

```
Action Barryvdh\TranslationManager\ActionsController@destroy not defined. (View:....
```

I use this route to resource, which works well for creating, editing and viewing models.

```
Route::resource('actions', 'ActionsController');
```

Can you please help me out? I have no clue how to resolve this classess problem. 
Worst part of the whole L5.

I thied to follow another advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643483/crud-laravel-4-how-to-link-to-destroy)

```
Route::get('actions/{id}/destroy',['as'=>'actions.destroy','uses'=>'ActionsController@destroy']);
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'delete','action'=>'actions/'.$o->id.'/destroy']) !!}
```

But I still see this:

```
Action Barryvdh\TranslationManager\actions/23/destroy not defined.
```

Comment: i have already tried all conceivable variations, including yours which is obviously wrong as it pointts to place where Models are placed. Really appreciate your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'delete','action'=>'actions'./$o->id) !!}

<button type="submit" class="fa fa-remove"></button>                      

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

the Delete method works:

```
/resource/{resource}
```