# get the row id from a groupBy in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a groupBy data it is working but I am wondering how can I get the row ID of the nested record?

**from my index function**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $collectorBorrowers = CollectorMember::get()
      ->groupBy('collector.name');
}

return view('dashboard.collector-members.index', compact('collectorBorrowers'));
```

Here's what my collector_member's table

[image]

Here's how I display the groupBy on my blade

```
@foreach ($collectorBorrowers as $collector => $users_list)
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5"
            style="background-color: #F7F7F7">{{ $collector }}: ({{ $users_list->count() }} borrowers)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($users_list as $user)
        <tr>
            <td><div class="profile-side-img rounded-circle" style="background:url({{ url('/storage/avatars/'.$user->borrower['avatar']) }});"><br/></div></td>
            <td><a href="/dashboard/users/{{ $user->borrower['id'] }}" target="_blank">{{ $user->borrower['name'] }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $user->borrower['email'] }}</td>
            <td>+{{ $user->borrower['country_code'] }}{{ $user->borrower['phone_number'] }}</td>
            <td>
                @if ($user->borrower['email_verified_at'])
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm trans" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email Verified"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></button>
                @else 
                    <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm trans"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></button>
                @endif

                @if ($user->borrower['phone_verified_at'])
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm trans" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Phone Number Verified"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></button>
                @else
                    <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm trans"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></button>
                @endif
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            {!! Form::open([
                'method'=>'DELETE',
                'url' => ['/dashboard/collector-members', $users_list],
                'style' => 'display:inline'
            ]) !!}
                {!! Form::button('<i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>', array(
                        'type' => 'submit',
                        'class' => 'btn btn-custom-danger btn-sm trans',
                        'title' => 'Remove user',
                        'onclick'=>'return confirm("Confirm delete?")',
                        'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                        'data-original-title' => 'Edit'
                )) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}                                             
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{-- {{dd($users_list)}} --}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

that gives me this output

[image]

everything is ok my only concern is the row id from collector_member's table so that i can remove the record from  specific collector.

is is possible? thanks!

**UPDATE:**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $collectorBorrowers = CollectorMember::get()
        ->keyBy('id')
        ->groupBy('collector.name');

    dd($collectorBorrowers);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to key collection by row ID before grouping:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-keyby

```php
$collectorBorrowers = CollectorMember::get()
      ->keyBy('id')
      ->groupBy('collector.name');
```

And then in your view traverse groups like that:

```html
@foreach ($users_list as $key => $user)
      ...
      {!! Form::open([
            'method'=>'DELETE',
            'url' => ['/dashboard/collector-members', $key],
      ]) !!}
      ...
@endforeach
```

P.S. Avoid Form Helper, cause it deprecated.

[Why are Form and HTML helpers deprecated in Laravel 5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695949/why-are-form-and-html-helpers-deprecated-in-laravel-5-x)

Comment: Thanks again @romanbobrik. But adding $key on `@foreach ($users_list as $key => $user)` just give me a sequence number of the nested foreach data e.g. 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: hm. can you show dump of keyed `$collectorBorrowers`?

Comment: I think I get it. i only need to put {{$user->id}}. thanks  a lot @roman