# Laravel href destroy

Tags: php, laravel, destroy

I am trying to delete an object without using forms. So what I did was improvising. I've made a route:

```
Route::get('category/destroyMe', ['uses' => 'CategoryController@destroyMe', 'as' => 'category.destroyMe']);
```

And in the view I am picking up the category id like so:

```
<a href="{{route('category.destroyMe', ['id' => $category->id])}}" ></a>
```

And finally the controller:

```
public function destroyMe()
{
    $this->destroy(Category::find(Input::get('id')));
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Question:**
I was wondering if there is a way to do this without my helper method `destroyMe()`? Is there a way to forward a `method = 'DELETE'` via href or something, so i can call my resource route like `category.destroy` without the need of complication?

**EDIT:**
I don't want to do it with forms (as I do know how to do it like that). Nor do I want to complicate with ajax or some extra scripts or something. I am wondering if there is a pure Laravel slick solution like

```
<a href="{{route('category.destroy', ['id' => $category->id, 'method' => 'DELETE])}}" ></a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRUD Laravel 4 how to link to destroy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643483/crud-laravel-4-how-to-link-to-destroy)

Comment: That duplicate doesn't answer my question

Comment: It at least has plenty suggestions about how to do a delete call to the server. It seems that generating a form with the form controller is the most spreaded way of doing it

Comment: It does, but you are not looking that my method works. So I am not looking for a working solution, but specific one :)

Comment: Well - then the simple answer is: no. There is no way to do a delete request with just a link. You always need a form or ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="{{ action('CategoryController@destroyMe', ['id' => $category->id]) }}" ></a>
```

And action:

```
public function destroyMe($id)
{
    Category::destroy($id);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: I guess that will create the same route

Comment: I guess my code is the simpliest way to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty slick, except that I need to modify the route itself to call 'destroyMe/{id}' or the code will break. However, I wanted to handle it using the resource destroy method withoud the need to create a new route at all

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog in which I can delete posts and this works for me

```
<a href="{{ route('delete-post', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">x</a>
```

The routing:

```
Route::get('delete/{post_id}', ['uses' => 'PostsController@delete', 'as' => 'delete-post']);
```

And the function in PostsController

```
public function delete($id) {
    Post::destroy($id);

    return redirect()->back()->with(["deleted" => "The post was deleted"]);
}
```