# Delete from laravel list

Tags: laravel

i am trying to create a delete and edit button so that i can data from list. please hel how i can do it. in laravel 5.4.Below is the interface of the application and the buttons codes. help on how the edit and delete will work.

```
<td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a> <!-- </td> -->
            <!-- <td> --><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{route('contacts.index', $contacts->id)}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete the contact');">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzp2c.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRUD Laravel 4 how to link to destroy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643483/crud-laravel-4-how-to-link-to-destroy)

Comment: You want to delete or edit a database entry after a button click, correct?

Comment: Yes! @RogerCreasy i want the button to delete individual list of contacts

Comment: OK...so, a button click to delete several database entries? Or, a button click to delete one database entry?

Comment: a button click to delete each one entry from the list and also from the database, obvious if u click the delete button it will delete from the list and database too